# Best way to check if JSON response is empty or null

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm just wondering if this is the best way to check if a JSON response is empty or NULL.

This is what I did so far. With this way, how would it figure out which JSON key is actually empty, and which is full, then how would it submit the correct one. That's why I was thinking of the second option. Am I just super over-thinking this?

```
if ((data.city.length > 0) || (data.region.length > 0) || (data.country.length > 0)) {
    $('#city').empty().append(data.city);
    $('#region').empty().append(data.region);
    $('#country').empty().append(data.country);
} else {
    $('#city').empty().append('No Info Available');
    $('#region').empty().append('No Info Available');
    $('#country').empty().append('No Info Available');
}
```

But then it got me thinking if this way would be better, it would be a lot longer though. Thoughts on this?

```
if ((data.city.length > 0) {
    $('#city').empty().append(data.city);
} else {
    $('#city').empty().append('No Info Available');
}

if ((data.country.length > 0) {
    $('#country').empty().append(data.country);
} else {
    $('#country').empty().append('No Info Available');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's the pattern you have, and it's consistent

```
$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $('#' + key).html(value || 'No Info Available');
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/op4tmsze/)

Comment: Wow, this is much simpler then what I was using. I will mark as answered when I can.